# CS50 Pset4 filters-less sepia doesn't output the correct RBG value with the formula

Tags: c, debugging, cs50

```
// Convert image to sepia
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int oRed;
    int oGreen;
    int oBlue;
    int sepiaBlue;
    int sepiaGreen;
    int sepiaRed;


    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            oRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            oGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            oBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            sepiaRed = round((.393 * oRed) + (.769 * oGreen) + (.189 * oBlue));
            sepiaGreen = round((.349 * oRed) + (.686 * oGreen) + (.168 * oBlue));
            sepiaRed = round((.272 * oRed) + (.534 * oGreen) + (.131 * oBlue));

            if (sepiaRed > 255)
            {
                sepiaRed = 255;
            }

            if (sepiaGreen > 255)
            {
                sepiaGreen = 255;
            }

            if (sepiaBlue > 255)
            {
                sepiaBlue = 255;
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = sepiaRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sepiaGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sepiaBlue;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

check results:

**testing with pixel (20, 40, 90)
running ./testing 1 0...
checking for output "56 50 39\n"...
Expected Output:
56 50 39
Actual Output:
39 50 0**

it simply outputs the wrong RGB values when I'm pretty sure I used the corect formula.
As shown below can't even get a single pixel right. Not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to experience unintentional blindness when dealing with repetitious code (copy/paste).

Discerning readers see **two** instances of `sepiaRed = round((...`
Ya gotta be careful...

Now that you see the bug, look again at what the good & bad reports were trying to tell you. Notice where the value `39` appears? Notice the value `0` in the *blue* channel?

---

Try to write more *compact* code, and use a layout and variable names that simplify scanning both horizontally and vertically:

```
// Convert image to sepia
void sepia( int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width] ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < width; j++ ) {
            int red = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            int grn = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            int blu = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;

            int sred = round((.393 * red) + (.769 * grn) + (.189 * blu));
            int sgrn = round((.349 * red) + (.686 * grn) + (.168 * blu));
            int sblu = round((.272 * red) + (.534 * grn) + (.131 * blu));

            image[i][j].rgbtRed     = (sred > 255) ? 255 : sred;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen   = (sgrn > 255) ? 255 : sgrn;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue    = (sblu > 255) ? 255 : sblu;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: damn it I knew it's something stupid like that thanks for the advice.